# Core Data Update in swift while selecting any row in list table view not working?

Tags: swift, core-data, ios9

I have got a scenario in which I have 2 VC which are -

VC1 - To enter detail & save the data.
VC2 - To display the datas in a table view.

Now I want that whenever I select any particular row I would update my Database at the particular row. For that I am passing the selected managed object at that particular row for which I use the following code.

VC2 class name - `ViewController`

Code to fetch request -

```
func fetchData()
{
    let appdelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appdelegate.managedObjectContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")

    do
    {
        people = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
        print(people)
        print("FETCHING DATA")

    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        print("could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    }
```

Code to pass the data in selected row -

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == "segueupdate"
        {

            let update = segue.destinationViewController as! EnterDetailViewController
          //  var managedobject = NSManagedObject()
            let indexpath = self.tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow

            let row = indexpath?.row
          let  managedobject = people[row!]

            update.managedobjectt = managedobject

        }
    }
```

VC2 class name - `EnterDetailViewController`

```
class EnterDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nametextfield: UITextField!
    var managedobjectt = NSManagedObject()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let s = managedobjectt.valueForKey("name") as? String
        {
            nametextfield.text = s //here I show the user the existing name value
        }

    }
```

Now in my save function I do -

```
@IBAction func savedata(sender: AnyObject)
    {

    let appdelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedcontext = appdelegate.managedObjectContext

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: managedcontext)

    let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedcontext)
    person.setValue(self.nametextfield.text, forKey: "name")

    do
    {
        try managedcontext.save()
        print("SAVED")

    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        print("could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

Here I want the compiler to check the received managed object and update any changes to the database which I am unable to do because SWIFT doesn't accept a managedobject type as condition but I was able to achieve update of database by this concept in ObjC.

And another problem is when I try to compile I get an error as -

> failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class
>   'NSManagedObject'

in the `prepereforsegue()` method. So how to solve the problem and perform update.

Comment: You should consider implementing an NSFetchedResultsController. Then you don't even have to worry about updating your data source because when your managed object context changes, so does your table view.

Comment: @Ian That is fine but how to pass a managed object type in my prepareForSegue() method so the compiler can know which object and attributes I am selecting to change.

Comment: https://github.com/imaccallum/CoreDataSegueDemo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong because you're trying to create an invalid managed object instance:

```
var managedobjectt = NSManagedObject()
```

It should be

```
var managedobjectt : NSManagedObject?
```

And when you update you aren't changing the current item if it exists, you're just always creating a new instance. You should

```
if let person = self.managedobjectt {
    // update (if anything other than below)
} else {
    // create new (insert and set any default values)
}

person.setValue(self.nametextfield.text, forKey: "name")

// save
```

Comment: Why is this so because SWIFT says that if you are creating an instance you can do so by giving () as I did by - var managedobjectt = NSManagedObject().  If that is not the case then when should be this type of declaration used?

Comment: It is true, but it also needs to be a designated initialiser

Comment: So what is the difference between the two can you clarify a bit as I am new to   Swift and struggling with different kinds of syntaxes. Your explannation could be of grt help to me.

Comment: Basically you can't create a managed object without an entity and context, to do so is invalid, and that's what that basic initialiser does...